# Make perfect scrollbar visible by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, custom-scrolling

I am using perfect scrollbar for custom scroll bar. It is working fine.

But the scrollbar is visible only when you  mouse over on the container.

How do I make this visible all the time?

```
$('.container').perfectScrollbar();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gbfLazpx/338/)**

Comment: I updated my answer after playing with your example. Copy and paste my code as in the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the perfectscrollbar wiki:

> How can I make the scrollbars always visible?
>
> The reason why it's hidden by default is that opacity: 0 is used.
>   Please change all references of it to opacity: 0.6. If using .scss,
>   modify the line @include opacity(0) to @include opacity(0.6) in the
>   scrollbar-rail-default mixin and run gulp build to build .css and
>   .min.css files.
>
> If you're not willing to modify the CSS files but would like to make
>   it always visible, please add following lines anywhere after
>   perfect-scrollbar.css is loaded.
>
> `.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail,
>    .ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {   opacity: 0.6; }`
>
> Also, an example code may be helpful to see how to achieve it.

Here is example https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/blob/master/examples/always-visible.html

So, if you modify your JSFiddle by pasting the following into your html, it works.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail,
    .ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {   opacity: 0.6; }
 </style>
```

Comment: Please update your fiddle. I added these lines to mine and it worked perfectly. Sorry I couldn't get a link for the fiddle.

Comment: .ps__rail-x,
    .ps__rail-y {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

Answer (score 3):

In addition you have to make sure perfect-scrollbar is updated at the right time. If the content is loaded dynamically, call `ps.update()`.

**Warning**, make sure the the call is made after your data is loaded, on VueJS I had to do it in the 'nextTick' function :

```
    this.$nextTick(() => {
          ps.update();
      });
    },
```

I guess a timeout may works too.

Comment: not the op issue but helped me for a div of variable height

Answer (score 3):

```
 .ps__rail-x,
.ps__rail-y {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will work even if the container class doesn't exist in you application

```
.ps> .ps__scrollbar-x-rail, .ps> .ps__scrollbar-y-rail{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ngx-perfect-scrollbar in **Angular 8** and fixed problem by adding the following styles

```
.ps > .ps__rail-x,
.ps > .ps__rail-y {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the mentioned CSS in your application.

```css
:host {
    ::ng-deep {

        .ps>.ps__rail-x>.ps__thumb-x,
        .ps>.ps__rail-x>.ps__thumb-x:hover,
        .ps>.ps__rail-x>.ps__thumb-x:focus {
            height: 10px;
            transition: inherit;
        }

        perfect-scrollbar>.ps.ps--active-x>.ps__rail-x {
            height: 10px;
            z-index: 9;
        }

        .ps>.ps__rail-x>.ps__thumb-x {
            background: #747f99;
        }

        perfect-scrollbar>.ps.ps--active-x>.ps__rail-x:hover,
        perfect-scrollbar>.ps.ps--active-x>.ps__rail-x.ps--clicking {
            height: 10px;
        }

        perfect-scrollbar>.ps.ps--active-y>.ps__rail-y:hover,
        perfect-scrollbar>.ps.ps--active-y>.ps__rail-y.ps--clicking {
            width: 10px;
        }

        .ps>.ps__rail-y>.ps__thumb-y,
        perfect-scrollbar>.ps.ps--active-y>.ps__rail-y {
            width: 10px;
            transition: inherit;
        }

        .ps>.ps__rail-y>.ps__thumb-y {
            background: #747f99;
        }

        .ps__rail-x {
            opacity: 0.9;
            background-color: #eee !important;
        }

        .ps__rail-y {
            opacity: 0.9;
            background-color: #eee !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>perfect-scrollbar example</title>
    <link href="../dist/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../dist/js/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <style>
      h1 { text-align: center; }
      .container { position:relative; margin:0px auto; padding:0px; width: 600px; height: 400px; overflow: auto; }
      .container .content { background-color: red; width: 1280px; height: 720px; }
    </style>
    <style>
      /* to make scrollbars always visible */
      .always-visible.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-x-rail,
      .always-visible.ps-container > .ps-scrollbar-y-rail {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Default</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Always visible</h1>
    <div class="container always-visible">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.container'), function (el) {
          Ps.initialize(el);
        });
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Make sure you are rendering the content first and after that you are creating the scrollbars. No CSS changes are needed. I'm using **perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js**